# Is it safe to manually edit the config file inside a bare repository created by gitolite's wild repo feature?

Tags: git, gitolite

Suppose I create an instance of a wild repo from the following signature.

```
 C  repos/CREATOR/[A-Za-z].*
```

If I then want to modify the `config` file for the specific instance I created, I could use [this method](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config.html) which is suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5063447/391161), which involves mentioning the created repo by name (inside the `gitolite.conf`) and then modifying the `rc` file to enable that feature.

Alternately, I could ssh to the system and just modify the `config` file under the bare repository directly to make it look the way I want.

If I choose this latter approach, is there any danger of `gitolite` clobbering my changes in the future, or corrupting the repository because it cannot handle the manual edits?

Answer (score 1):

If you consider the source which actually set the config settings ([`triggers/post-compile/update-git-configs`](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/triggers/post-compile/update-git-configs#L36), it does so for a [POST_COMPILE step](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/lib/Gitolite/Hooks/PostUpdate.pm#L42), which means each time you are pushing `gitolite.conf`.

That can potentially reset a config setting value to the one specified in `gitolite.conf` when it is pushed *after* you have directly modified the config in the bare repo on the server (which can then be read with the [`gitolite git-config` command](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/dc8b590a0562ab7dc4bdab9511fe6c31cb422ae8/src/commands/git-config)) .

So yes, there is a risk of the value being changed.